# How can I write a test code in c++

Tags: c++, unit-testing

```
BufferContainer::BufferContainer( uint8_t* buffer, size_t size, size_t usz):
            buffer_ptr(buffer),
            buffer_position(0),
            total_size(size),
            required_size(0),
            used_size(0) {}
```

I need to test the above constructor (unit testing) . Please help!

Comment: There's no logic there, so nothing really needs testing. Except perhaps the design of the constructor.... (unused parameters are rarely a good idea)

Comment: Call it then check post conditions with your getters ?

Comment: what do you want to test in your unit test(s)?

Comment: @Hcorg  write an unit test to cover above function(code coverage)

Comment: Jarod42 please let me know in code terms

Comment: @1User it's not a function, it's constructor. as Mat points - there's no logic in here, so it's hard to unit test. You could just write constructor and check by getters it set all what is needed, but that's not really a good test...

Comment: @Hcorg  as a part of code coverage , i must need to write an test for constructors also ..so i am seeking help

Comment: constructor coverage should be included in 'normal' unit-tests - when you want to test *functionality* of BufferContainer you have to construct it, then call some method on it. Unit test will test behavior of method, yet constructor will be also tested (as precondition of method) and code should be covered

Answer (score 2):

You are testing a constructor, you cannot just invoke it like a normal function. Even if you were able to do that, the issue is that constructors don't return anything so you cannot see if they did the work they were intended to do.

Constructors initialize internal state of the object. So the best way is to

- Create an instance of BufferContainer.
- I am sure there would be other methods of this class that rely upon the internal state. Create test cases that tests these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the following steps:

1. Use the constructor for creating a object `A`.
2. Check the value of member variable in `A`. According to checking the value of member variable, you can assure that whether your constructor works well or not.

**EDIT**: In order to check the private member in `A`, you should provide the `get()` function. For example:

```
`class Example
{
public:
    Example(const int& a):_a(a){}
    ~Example(){}
    const int& get() const
    {
        return _a;
    }
private:
    int _a;
}`
```

When you test, you can do as it:

```
int main()
{
    Example A(5);
    std::cout << A.get() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Regarding point 2 above, I don't think it is a good idea to check private member variables in unit tests. Look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618710/unit-test-accessing-private-variables

Comment: @Paani, if it is a private member, you can use `get()` function to get the value of member ！

Comment: Sure, but only if such a getter function was part of the actual requirements from the class. It won't be a good idea to add public getters just for unit testing.