# Java INFO Extract On Console

Tags: java, logging, printing

In Eclipse Java I am using Print API and when attempting to print receive INFO messages as such:

Oct 31, 2011 5:48:58 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i

Oct 31, 2011 5:48:59 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i

Is there any way to extract the message that INFO gives that is "unsupported/disabled operation: i". Perhaps a get() method somehow? Thanks

Comment: Is that the `java.util.logging` API or log4j being used?

Comment: I don't put any code to do logging, so its whatever is default

Answer (score 1):

The messages you are looking for are stored in `org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine#unsupportedOperators` field of `Set<String>` type.

Unfortunately this field is `private final` with no accessors (?) You can use reflection to obtain it, but this is far from being elegant. Nevertheless see: [How do I read a private field in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192)

However I cannot say that writing a custom logging appender (which is a second solution) is more elegant... You haven't mentioned which logging framework you use. Looks like `java.util.logging`, check out [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Frtrb_createhandler.html). For Log4J [this](http://mytechattempts.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/log4j-custom-memory-appender/) will be a good start.

Comment: Looks like PDFBox uses Apache's commons logging. So I'm guessing it's trying to find a suitable framework at runtime and comes up with `java.util.logging`.