# Getting value of private not primitive field using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Presume we have two different packages... one package can't be accessed but we like to know the value of a complex field called b.

```
public class A {
    private String  whatever;
    private B       b;

    private static class B {
         final ArrayList<Z> c   = new ArrayList<Z>();

         private void addItem(Z z) {
                this.c.add(z);
         }

         private Z getItem(int nr) {
                return this.c.get(nr);
          }
     }
}

public class Reflect extends A {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
            Reflect ref = new Reflect();
            Class getA = ref.getClass().getSuperclass();
            Field getB = getDeclaredField("b");
            getB.setAccessible(true);
            Class bInst = getB.getClass();
            Method bMeth = bInst.getMethod("getItem", Integer.TYPE);
            Object zInst = bMeth.invoke(new Integer(123));
      }
}
```

How can I get the value if I don't get the complex type B from the package ? 
Still get **java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: stackOver.A.getItem(int)** even I set the field gstB accessible ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you are missing is that getField only gives you public accessible fields.

```
 Field getB = getA.getDeclaredField("b");
```

will give you any field of that class.

---

A longer example

```
class Main {
    public static class A {
        private String whatever;
        private B b = new B();

        private static class B {
            final ArrayList<String> c = new ArrayList<String>();

            private void addItem(String z) {
                this.c.add(z);
            }

            private String getItem(int nr) {
                return this.c.get(nr);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Reflect extends A {
        public static void main(String... ignored) throws Exception {
            Reflect ref = new Reflect();
            Class getA = ref.getClass().getSuperclass();
            Field getB = getA.getDeclaredField("b");
            getB.setAccessible(true);
            Object b = getB.get(ref);

            Method addItem = b.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("addItem", String.class);
            addItem.setAccessible(true);
            addItem.invoke(b, "Hello");

            Method getItem = b.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getItem", int.class);
            getItem.setAccessible(true);
            String hi = (String) getItem.invoke(b, 0);
            System.out.println(hi);
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
Hello
```

Comment: this is not working as B is private and therefor it s not visible... even with  getB.setAccessible(true); I don't know how I can access a method of B...

Comment: To access an instance method of B you need to have an instance of B.  Reflection doesn't change this fact in any way.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get the value if I don't get the complex type B from the package ?

You can get it as an `Object`, and then use reflection to further discover the methods that it exposes.

```
Object bInst = ... // Get b through reflection
Class bClass = bInst.getClass();
Method[] bMeth = bClass.getMethod("getItem", Integer.TYPE);
Object zInst = bMeth.invoke(new Integer(123));
```

Comment: which means I have to loop through B to get the full object... thus if I have heaps of complex objects I have to run through all objects ...

Comment: @Fendrix This is correct: if you do not have access to a type at compile time, you need to loop through objects, potentially even recursing down the object hierarchy.

Comment: I thought I could somehow get the Object directly... thanks anyway ...:)

Comment: @Fendrix Ah, I thought you already found a link on how to get private variables through reflection. Here is [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1196192/335858) to a very good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [commons beanutils library](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html) and use following method, it is much cleaner than doing it yourself

```
PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty(ref, "b.propertyOfClassB");
```

replace propertyOfClassB with actual property name.