# Get all private fields using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, field, private

I wonder is there a way to get all private fields of some class in Java and their type.

For example lets suppose I have a class:

```
class SomeClass {
    private String aaa;
    private SomeOtherClass bbb;
    private double ccc;
}
```

Now I would like to get all private fields (`aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`) of class `SomeClass` (Without knowing name of all fields upfront) and check their type.

Comment: @atk Nobody's forcing you to answer; but for many of us landing on this question from Google, the top answer is a far more succinct explanation than reading through long posts on reflection. Even the long-tail of questions like this contribute to what SO is today.

Comment: See [How do I read a private field in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1196192)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

It is possible to obtain all fields with the method `getDeclaredFields()` of `Class`. Then you have to check the modifier of each fields to find the private ones:

```
List<Field> privateFields = new ArrayList<>();
Field[] allFields = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : allFields) {
    if (Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())) {
        privateFields.add(field);
    }
}
```

Note that `getDeclaredFields()` will not return inherited fields.

Eventually, you get the type of the fields with the method [Field.getType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29).

Comment: I think the fact that I'm working against a compiled class makes it quite inconvenient because the returned fields have names such as `m0`, `m1`, etc., and are of type `java.lang.reflect.Method`. This could be due to me trying to use reflection on a Spring Bean casted to an interface?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `Modifier` to determine if a field is private.  Be sure to use the `getDeclaredFields` method to ensure that you retrieve private fields from the class, calling `getFields` will only return the public fields.

```
public class SomeClass {

    private String aaa;
    private Date date;
    private double ccc;
    public int notPrivate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Field> fields = getPrivateFields(SomeClass.class);
        for(Field field: fields){
            System.out.println(field.getName());
        }
    }

    public static List<Field> getPrivateFields(Class<?> theClass){
        List<Field> privateFields = new ArrayList<Field>();

        Field[] fields = theClass.getDeclaredFields();

        for(Field field:fields){
            if(Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())){
                privateFields.add(field);
            }
        }
        return privateFields;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan why did you change my edit "clazz" to "class", when we clearly need to use the variable "clazz" and not the keyword "class"

Comment: I am sorry for that mistake, I thought this was a mistake as there was no variable assosiated with the document or the code anywhere! Pardon me for that..

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan there was a variable, it is in the arguments of the method. Though, do you care to revoke your change, since I can't change it.

Answer (score 11):

Try [`FieldUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html) from apache commons-lang3:

```
FieldUtils.getAllFieldsList(Class<?> cls)
```

Answer (score 9):

### Check if a Field is private

You could **filter the Fields** using [Modifier.isPrivate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#isPrivate%28int%29):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
// ...
Field field = null;
// retrieve the field in some way
// ...
Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())
```

on a single `Field` object which returns `true` if the field is `private`

---

### Collect all Fields of a class

To **collect the all the Fields** use:

1) If you need only the fields of the the class without the fields taken from the class hierarchy you could simply use:

```
Field[] fields = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

2) If you don't want to reinvent the wheel and get all the fields of a class hierarchy you could rely upon [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) version 3.2+ which provides [`FieldUtils.getAllFieldsList`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html#getAllFieldsList(java.lang.Class)):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.AbstractCollection;
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.AbstractSequentialList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class FieldUtilsTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetAllFieldsList() {

        // Get all fields in this class and all of its parents
        final List<Field> allFields = FieldUtils.getAllFieldsList(LinkedList.class);

        // Get the fields form each individual class in the type's hierarchy
        final List<Field> allFieldsClass = Arrays.asList(LinkedList.class.getFields());
        final List<Field> allFieldsParent = Arrays.asList(AbstractSequentialList.class.getFields());
        final List<Field> allFieldsParentsParent = Arrays.asList(AbstractList.class.getFields());
        final List<Field> allFieldsParentsParentsParent = Arrays.asList(AbstractCollection.class.getFields());

        // Test that `getAllFieldsList` did truly get all of the fields of the the class and all its parents 
        Assert.assertTrue(allFields.containsAll(allFieldsClass));
        Assert.assertTrue(allFields.containsAll(allFieldsParent));
        Assert.assertTrue(allFields.containsAll(allFieldsParentsParent));
        Assert.assertTrue(allFields.containsAll(allFieldsParentsParentsParent));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using Java 8 :

```
Field[] fields = String.class.getDeclaredFields();
List<Field> privateFieldList = Arrays.asList(fields).stream().filter(field -> Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())).collect(
        Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean like

```
Field[] fields = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

Comment: This excludes any inherited fields.