# Finding all private fields without NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, reflection

I want to dynamically create a class composition map by enumerating private fields of a given set of classes. This works well with [getDeclaredFields()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) with an isolated set of classes.

But if the class contains a field which type is a class that is not available, the call fails with `NoClassDefFoundError`. Is there any way to enumerate private fields so that I can avoid this behaviour, for example one by one and catching the exception and carry on with rest of the fields?

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java) helps you

Comment: also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315368/java-reflection-get-all-private-fields) one

Comment: I believe you could do this by writing your own custom `ClassLoader` in which when trying to load the class of a field whose class cannot be found you could handle the exception yourself and return another `Class` or the class of a `Proxy`. But imo, it's hacky and it just doesn't worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended finding the solution:

I can use ASM library's `ClassReader`to visit each field and grab it's name.

Unfortunately even knowing the name is not enough for Reflection to become useful as  `Class.getDeclaredField(name_taken_from_classreader)` will still call `getDeclaredFields()` for some reason.

The discussion that pointed me there can be found [here](https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/reflecting-fields-that-have-classes-from-unloaded-plugins.160959/).

Answer (score 1):

Not through reflection, no. The only way to get all fields dynamically (ie. without knowing their names) of a given type is with `getDeclaredFields()`. This is a batch query which constructs a `Field` instance for each field. If a single one of these fails, the whole call fails.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get you answered the question. You can enumerate the fields one by one into a try catch(NoClassDeFoundError) block and if there was an exception do nothing with that field in your catch block and go to the other field. Is it the thing that you are looking for or I misunderstood your  problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there any way to enumerate private fields so that I can avoid this behaviour, for example one by one and catching the exception and carry on with rest of the fields?**

I don't think this is the right approach. You should not *catch* errors. `NoClassDefFoundError` is an Error.

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems
>   that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such
>   errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error, though a
>   "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most
>   applications should not try to catch it.