# handle different instance variables in method

Tags: java, methods, instance-variables

So if I have a method where a variable can be an instance of a bunch of different classes where only some of them have a specific instance variable, how do I use this instance variable in the method without getting the `cannot be resolved or is not a field` error?

consider this code:

```
void method1(){
    SuperType randomInstance = getRandomInstance();
    if(randomInstance.stop == true) //do something
}
```

where `SuperType` is a super class to all possible instances that `randomInstance` can hold.

However, an instance doesn't necessarily have the variable `stop` so I get an error saying `stop cannot be resolved or is not a field`

So my question is, is there a way to get around this or would I have to create different methods for different instances depending on if they have the variable `stop` or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If having a `stop` property can be viewed as a behavior shared by some of the sub-classes of `SuperType`, you can consider defining an interface - let's call it `Stoppable` - having methods `getStop` (or perhaps `isStopped` if it's a boolean) and `setStop`.

Then your code can look like :

```
void method1(){
    SuperType randomInstance = getRandomInstance();
    if (randomInstance instanceof Stoppable) {
        Stoppable sInstance = (Stoppable) randomInstance;
        if(sInstance.getStop() == ...) //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Aah that was actually exactly what I was looking for, I knew I had read about this somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

Give the classes in question a common supertype or interface (they seem, from your code, to have one — `SuperType`), and define the instance field (it's not a "variable") on the supertype or define a getter function on the interface. (Actually, even if the supertype is a class, it's commonly best practice to define the field using a getter anyway, even if you *could* make it a `public` or `protected` instance field.)

Comment: Well yes they have a supertype but it is not something that I can change since I am using a framework. But I will just create a mutual interface, it will work fine.

Comment: @PandaDeTapas: Yup, there you go. Adding an interface of your own with this in it is [Eran's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30776852/157247), I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change your class hiearchy with the introdution of an Interface (`Stoppable` for example) can resort to reflection to detect if the class has a provate field named stop.

You can find an example of field "listing" from a class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315368/java-reflection-get-all-private-fields) and Field is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html)