# How to do reflection in java?

Tags: java, reflection, minecraft

So there is this class that holds a ServerData field:

```
public class Minecraft implements IPlayerUsage{

    // others

    private ServerData currentServerData;

    // others

    public void setServerData(ServerData par1ServerData)
    {
        this.currentServerData = par1ServerData;
    }
}
```

How can i accsess to this : `mc.currentServerData.serverIP` form another class w/ reflection?

Comment: see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Reflection API tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) at Oracle that might be interesting for you.