# intern() string of query result

Tags: java, string, performance, jpa

I need to interning string which result of my query. 
Because my queries first field always contains "0" or "1", and every time its creates new String object.
And I want to use intern() on this string and use pool for saving some memory.
[image]
But my statement return a number:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN b.num >= 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as "result", 
        ROUND (((b.num - 12)/12),2) AS "weight" FROM (SELECT sum(t.amount_inst) AS num 
    FROM MRCH_CARD t 
    ....
```

So its result in java side was  BigDecimal, not String:
[image]

But inside BigDecimal exists stringCache field with String value, and every time when I call that query as result of exection its creating new String Object with "1" or "0" value. 
How can I intern() that value to string pool?
I tried that way, but I think this didnt work, because qr.getSingleResult() already created new String Object as stringCache field of BigDecimal:

```
  Object[] tempResult = (Object [])qr.getSingleResult();
  result.setResult(new BigDecimal(tempResult[0].toString().intern()));
  result.setWeight(new BigDecimal(tempResult[1].toString().intern()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much better solution would be to use the number (int) for the first column. This should work:

```
 BigDecimal result = resultAsBigDecimal( (Number)tempResult[0] );

 public static BigDecimal resultAsBigDecimal( Number value ) {
     int i = value.intValue();
     if( 0 == i ) return BigDecimal.ZERO;
     if( 1 == i ) return BigDecimal.ONE;
     throw new RuntimException( "Unexpected value: " + value );
 }
```

`intern()` for the weight is probably useless. since the weight is going to be many different values.

Comment: Object[] tempResult = (Object [])qr.getSingleResult();
after that line, already created new String object("0" or "1"), in stringCache field of BigDecimal, so I dont understand how  help me  usage:
  BigDecimal result = resultAsBigDecimal( (Number)tempResult[0] );

Comment: What is "qr"? Why is it returning Strings?

Comment: Query qr = em.createNativeQuery(stmt);
I dont know why, my statement returned number, but BigDecimal contains stringCache field, and I dont know why. Pls see
http://prntscr.com/5mlp17

Comment: What is the type of `tempResult[0]`?

Comment: BigDecimal as you can see on image at my question

Comment: Okay, I see you use OpenJPA. Which version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67923/discussion-between-meetjoeblack-and-aaron-digulla).

Answer (score 0):

1) You could modify the SQL query to return a string instead of an integer

2) You could cache ("manually intern") the BigDecimal object itself - by replacing them with the BigDecimal.ONE and BigDecimal.ZERO static cached values

3) The private field stringCache in BigDecinal will be calculated only if you call toString() on the BigDecinal object - but if you need toString(), then you can probably throw away the BigDecinal object

4) (not recommended!) You could call intern even on a private string with reflection, see [How do I read a private field in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java)

Comment: The second option is not necessary IMO. There already are `BigDecimal.ONE` and `BigDecimal.ZERO`, so the OP should use them instead of creating a new `BigDecimal` object every time

Comment: @BackSlash good point, I'll edit the answer. But note that the Op is not creating these objects, they are coming from JDBC