# Use eStorage in EMF

Tags: java, eclipse-emf

In my `EObject` I have the field `eStorage`, which contains data, I want to use.

Is there a possibility to read out the eStorage?

I tried the code below but it doesn't work:

```
doIt(EObject object) {
    object.getEStorage;
    // use the eStorage...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that `eStorage` is a private field.

So either,

- Re-read the javadoc of the EObject interface and/or the javadoc of the particular implementation of EObject you're using. You may find a method offering the data you're looking for.
- Access the private field via Reflection

```
try {
    Field f = object.getClass().getDeclaredField("eStorage"); 
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Object theDataYouWant = f.get(object);
} catch(Exception e) {
    // Handle exception here...
}
```

References: [How do I read a private field in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1196207/363573)

Comment: Reflection did the job (as the eStorage field is private). Many Thanks! :)