# Handling association with JNI

Tags: java, c++, pointers, java-native-interface

I have question regarding how to correctly handle association (or depedency) in JNI.

Lets assume that in your shared library you have 2 classes, `NativeClass1` and `NativeClass2`. `NativeClass1` has a method `void fooNative(NativeClass2* nativeObj)` which allows it to perform some operation with an object of type `NativeClass2`.

For each of these classes, a java class is defined to wrap the corresponding native object (`JavaClass1` and `JavaClass2`, each one having a `long` private member pointing to a dynamically allocated native object of type `NativeClass1`and `NativeClass2`, respectively).

I would like `JavaClass1` to also have a method `public void fooJava(JavaClass2 obj)` (and a corresponding native method `private native void call_fooNative(long nativeObject1Ptr, long nativeObject2Ptr)` which will eventually call `NativeClass1::void fooNative(NativeClass2* nativeObj)` after casting the pointers).

How you would get the underlying long pointer (to a `NativeClass2`) member from `JavaClass2` in order to call `void JavaClass1::call_fooNative(long nativeObject1Ptr, long nativeObject2Ptr)` ( assuming you pass a pointer of to `NativeClass1` as the first parameter)?

I thought of 2 methods:

1. Creating a public getter method for the long pointer from `JavaClass2`.

But everybody could have access to the actual native object, create another shared library, perform a `delete ptr` on the void pointer of `NativeClass2` or damage the native ojbect in some other way.

2. Instead of passing the pointer to the `NativeClass2` object (as the second parameter from `call_fooNative(...)`, pass the actual java object of type `JavaClass2` and determine the pointer with `getFieldId` and `getLongField` (which is permited on a private member, as stated in The Java Native Interface: Programmer's Guide and Specification By Sheng Liang, "10.9 Violating Access Control Rules".

Which one would be the correct way in terms of design and security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How you would get the underlying long pointer (to a NativeClass2) member from JavaClass2 in order to call void JavaClass1::call_fooNative(long nativeObject1Ptr, long nativeObject2Ptr) (assuming you pass a pointer of to NativeClass1 as the first parameter)?

Your first method can be reasonable. It's the method used by [SWIG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG).

SWIG is an open-source tool that generates Java wrappers for C++ code. If you're wrapping a lot of classes or methods, you may want to consider using it.

For example, here's some code generated by SWIG (with the class name changed):

```
public class Foo {
  private long swigCPtr;
  protected boolean swigCMemOwn;

  public Foo(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
    swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  public static long getCPtr(Foo obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }

  ...
```

> But everybody could have access to the actual native object, create another shared library, perform a delete ptr on the void pointer of NativeClass2 or damage the native object in some other way.

Not necessarily everybody -- just Java and native code that has access to a reference to a particular instance of NativeClass2.

> 2. Instead of passing the pointer to the NativeClass2 object (as the second parameter from call_fooNative(...), pass the actual java object of type JavaClass2 and determine the pointer with getFieldId and getLongField ...

This won't necessarily prevent access to the pointer from Java. Java code can [use reflection to access private fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java).

Comment: Ok, then I'll go with my first method. Thanks for the details!