# Why Spring's ReflectionUtils marked as "Only intended for internal use"?

Tags: spring, reflection

Can I use this library? Or is it not desirable? And why?

I was trying to find answer, but have found nothing about this warning.

If usage of this library is not good idea, may be you will able to advise me another library.

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it and I think the chances of Spring changing it are quite small, **but** there's no **concrete intention** from the Spring development team to keep that class as it's, as opposed to what they do with their public/non-internal APIs.

So if it changes in the future, the spring guys won't be accepting any complains of the type *'but my code depends on that class and you change it!*.