# How do I mock a class with private fields?

Tags: java, testing, reflection, mockito

I'm trying to test a singleton class with Mockito, something like this:

```
  public class Single {
     private ID id;
     private Single(){}  //private constructor 
     public static Single getSingle(){ // ***code to get instance*** }

     // method I want to test
     public String getName(){ 
        String name = id.getRawName(); // need field id here
        ** additional operations on name ** // code need to be tested
        return name;
     }

  }
```

I tried to mock this class and set field "id" with reflection, like this:

```
Single sg = Mockito.mock(Sincle.class);
Field myID = sg.getClass().getDeclaredField("id"); // fails here
myID.setAccessible(true);
myID.set(sg, <ID instance>);
```

However it fails at `getDeclaredField()` method, with exception

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: id

I guess it's because `id` field is `null` in instance sg.

So I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to test this method without modify the original class?

Comment: It looks like this answer to this question may help explain some of this behavior. Not entirely sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just `when(sg.getId()).thenReturn("123")`?  The point of mocking is to mimic the external API of a unit, which means the internals should generally be irrelevant.

Comment: If I had to guess why the reflection itself is failing, it would be that `sg.getClass()` returns some dynamic class created by Mockito, which extends `Single`.  Using `Single.class.getDeclaredField("id")` would probably work.  But you'd still be left with a pretty terrible test IMO.

Comment: @MarkPeters  Thank you for your response. I think your guess makes more sense than mine. And I just modified my example a little to explain why I can't use Mockito.when(). And could you explain a little bit more why this would be a terrible test?

Comment: @hj690: From your edit it seems like `ExternalCall` is what you should be mocking.

Comment: @hj690 Please don't edit important technical details out of your question. I was quoting that portion of your question in my answer, and I'd like to ensure that my answer continues to make sense to help all future readers of this question (in addition to you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A mock is not a real object. You can't set a declared field of a mock because it doesn't exist<sup>1</sup>!

When you are writing tests, you generally want to mock all the classes that are **not**:

- The [**System Under Test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) (in this case, the `Single`) class
- Data Structures (like `List`) and other [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)s.

Therefore, the thing you really want to be mocking is `ExternalCall`, which you don't really explain how it works in your question. However, if it's a static method, you need to use [`PowerMock`](https://github.com/jayway/powermock). See: [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21105403/)

Note that your error is [`NoSuchFieldException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchFieldException.html), because you don't actually have a real instance. It's **not** because:

> I guess it's because `id` field is `null` in instance sg.

It's because the field **actually** doesn't exist<sup>1</sup> *in the mockito generated subclass*, not because it's `null`.

<sub>1: It does exist in mock's superclass (in this case, `Single`), but its value is captured by the mocking behavior and is ignored unless you use it as a partial mock. However, this is a technical detail and not relevant to the proper using of Mockito.</sub>

Comment: @MarkPeters I just edited my example more to explain why I can't just mock ExternalCall.

Comment: @hj690 How is `ID` set in your actual app?

Comment: @hj690 I don't recommend it, but once you're using a real `Single` object, you can set *that* field with Reflection. But it's better to do it with the way it works in your real app.

Answer (score 0):

> ...anything I can do to test this method without modify the
>   original class?

Yes, there is. Use Mockito for its bread-and-butter purposes:

`when(sg.getId()).thenReturn("123")`