# package scope access in Java and Android

Tags: java, android

I've noticed the strange behavior with package scope in Java and Android.

1. I've created the package "java.util.concurrent" in my project
2. Next I added class TestClass in just created package

   ```
   package java.util.concurrent;

   public class TestClass {

      public void testMethod() {

          ArrayBlockingQueue s = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1);
          // I can use items field.
          Object[] items = s.items;

      }

   }
   ```
3. The field items of ArrayBlockingQueue class has final package scope

   ```
   public class ArrayBlockingQueue<E> extends AbstractQueue<E>
           implements BlockingQueue<E>, java.io.Serializable {


       ....                

       /** The queued items */
       final Object[] items;

       ....

   }
   ```

Next, when I'm trying to compile the TestClass with usual Java Project (java 1.8.6x). I get success and it's logical.

But same class in Android project returns compile time error. The reason is 'my class hasn't access to this field'.

Have you any ideas?

*UPDATE*

The screen bellow displays the version of Android and code of Queue class

[image]

Comment: From where do you access it? From same package in both cases?

Comment: What version of android?

Comment: I've added screen. Version API is 23

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the Android version of `ArrayBlockingQueue` is not the same as the Java version. In Android, the `items` are [actually private](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java). That would make sense as to why it is out of scope. You can work around this, with reflection you can [gain access to private variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java) (not sure about **final** private)

Comment: Kevin's right. For example: openjdk defines items as: `private final E[] items;`

Comment: Wow, can't believe I made that mistake (that its openjdk instead of android source). Thanks for the correct

Comment: I've added screen which displays the version of Android and items field with package scope.

Comment: I can't find a good explanation for you on this. I agree, it should be working. Might be some android witchcraft at work resulting in your class not actually being in the same package.

Comment: @Kevin Yep, I agree with you, I found other classes with same behavior in Android and it's very strange.