# Determining What Object From an Array to Use Based On Private Field

Tags: java

I'm using a class and main of my own devising. To do the simulation I need to, I need to determine what object from an array of identical objects contains the greatest of a certain private field. For example,

```
Robot[] set = new Robot [7];
//initialize here, and do other stuff
```

At this point, I need to figure out which object within Robot has the greatest value of a certain field, which we'll call `myBeepers`, and tell that Robot to run a method, which we'll call `dropAllBeepers`. And that is where the problem lies, because

1. How do I call Math.max for something like this, and then call the corresponding object?
2. I need extremely efficient code (in terms of methods called, not execution time. It's complicated, but in short, I need to call as few methods as possible), and a for-loop would cost me an extreme amount of memory, so that's out of the question.

In short, how do I get this down to a single line? Something like:

```
Math.max (set.getBeepers()).dropAllBeepers();
```

Except this doesn't work because Math.max turns in a variable, not the object.

Comment: A for loop on an array of length `7` would cost you an extreme amount of memory? How?

Comment: I'm using this for a competition that uses a unique way of determining code size. Obviously, it wouldn't take up an extreme amount of memory in real coding, but it does in their system.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet would be to do something in the Robot class , something like this :

```
public static int maximum = 0;

public void setBeepers(int n){
   if (n>maximum){
       maximum = n;
   }
  this.n = n;
}
```

In that way maximum would always contain the maximum value and you won't need any other function or for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Robot implements Comparable on myBeepers field.

```
Robot[] sortedRobots = Arrays.sort(robots);
sortedRoborts[sortedRobots.length -1].dropAllBeepers();
```

Answer (score -1):

tried looking at reflection API ?
[How do I read a private field in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java)

if you want to have totally external solution you can use comparator API with reflection API and sort the list.

if you can change the code of class implement compareTo method