# How can I display a variable from another class without using getters and setters?

Tags: java

I'm a first-year student and I'm really struggling here. This is one of the questions that I have to do for my Assignment (I am allowed to use StackOverflow for guidance).

Create a class named `Customer` that will determine the monthly repayment amount due by a customer for a product bought on credit. The class has five fields: `customer name`, `contact number`, `product price`, `number of months`, and `the monthly repayment amount`.

Write get and set methods for each field, except for the monthly repayment amount field. The set methods must prompt the user to enter the values for the following fields: `customer name`, `contact number`, `product price`, and a `number of months`.

This class also needs a method to calculate the monthly repayment amount (product price divided by the number of months).

Add a subclass named `Finance_Period` that will determine if a customer will pay interest or not.

If the number of months to pay for the product is greater than three, the customer will pay 25% interest, or else no interest applies.

The maximum number of months to pay for the product is 12.

Override the `calculate_repayment()` method by determining if the customer will pay interest or not and calculate the monthly repayment amount.

Create a class called `Customer_Finance` that contains the logic to test the two classes.

Prompt the user for data for the first object where no interest applies and display the results; then prompt the user for data where interest is applicable and displays the results.

I'm struggling to call `amtRepay` into my main without using `getters` and `setters`.

I'm not even sure if I understand the question correctly, any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I have another class called `Finace_Period`, there is nothing there yet, I'm not 100% sure of what I'm doing yet.

This is my main class, where I want to display `amtRepay`.

```
package main;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Main {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Variables
        String name;
        int cNumber, months;
        double price;
        
        //Input
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the customer's name:");
        cNumber = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the customer's contact number:"));
        price = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the price of the product:"));
        months = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the number of repayment months:"));
        
        Customer c = new Customer(name, cNumber, months, price);
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, c.calcaAmtRepay());
                  
        }
    
    }
```

and this is my secondary class, where `amtRepay` is calculated.

```
package Main;

public class Customer extends Finance_Period {
    
    //Atributes
    private String name;
    private int cNumber, months;
    private double price, amtRepay;
    
    //Constructors
    public Customer (String name, int cNumber, int months, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cNumber = cNumber;
        this.months = months;
        this.price = price;
       
        
    }

    //Getters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getcNumber() {
        return cNumber;
    }
    
    public int getMonths() {
        return months;
    }
    
     public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
     
    //Setter
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setcNumber(int cNumber) {
        this.cNumber = cNumber;
    }

    public void setMonths(int months) {
        this.months = months;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    //Calculation of monthly repayments
    public double calcAmtRepay () {
       
        amtRepay = price / months;
        
        return price / months;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is your output from your main class?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: main.Customer
 at main.Main.main(Main.java:25)

It just gives me this error when it comes to outputting amtRepay

@jaSnom

Comment: First off, i think that you need to define another constructor, since your default constructor is expecting AmtRepay, which you are not passing. therefore you could define a new Constructor hat only cointains the Paramters you are passing:
```public Customer (String name, int cNumber, int months, double price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cNumber = cNumber;
    this.months = months;
    this.price = price;
  
}```

Comment: Also private Variables cannot be directly accessed. You need to make them either public or define a getter. In this Case a getter would be enough since you do not want to change it from the outsied, if im correct.

Comment: Okay, but I can't use getters and setters? I have removed the amtRepay from my constructer.

Comment: Solutions provided here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-to-read-the-value-of-a-private-field-from-a-different-class-in-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203915/java-get-private-variable-from-another-class-without-setting-a-getter

Comment: I looked at these, but i have no idea how to apply this to my code.

Comment: If both your classes are in the same package main, make sure the first line in Customer.java is `package main;`and not `package Main;` Java is very sensible about lowercase/uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

Change your constructor: leave the amtRepay argument.

```
//Constructors
public Customer (String name, int cNumber, int months, double price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cNumber = cNumber;
    this.months = months;
    this.price = price;
}
```

Be aware that after the call to this constructor, the amtRepay field is still not calculated. Better: you don't even need the amtRepay field in Customer as its value is calculated each time you call `calcAmtRepay()` which is a good idea because otherwise you have to recalculate it also in `setMonths` and `setPrice`.

```
public double calcAmtRepay () {
    return price / months;    
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, c.calcAmtRepay());
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesnt't work" ? What is the error you got ? Compilation error, runtime error ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: main.Customer
 at main.Main.main(Main.java:25) 
This is what i get

Answer (score 0):

In your class `main.Main` you are referring to class `main.Customer`, but according to the code you posted you only have class `Main.Customer`.

Change `package Main;` to `package main;` in your `Customer.java` and it should work.

Edit:

I don't have Netbeans so I used Visual Studio Code with Java extensions installed.

I created an empty directory. Inside that directory I created file `build.xml` and subdirectory `src`. Inside `src` I created package `main` and copied your code. I also created empty class `main.Finance_Period`.

My IDE notified me that class `main.Customer` has method `calcAmtRepay()`, but in class `main.Main` you call `calcaAmtRepay()` - notice the additional, lowercase `a` between `calc` and `Amt`. I fixed that and then added the following to my `build.xml`:

```
<project name="MyProject" default="dist" basedir=".">
  <description>
    Java assignment build file
  </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="src"/>
  <property name="build" location="build"/>
  <property name="dist" location="dist"/>

  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init"
        description="compile the source">
    <!-- Compile the Java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="dist" depends="compile"
        description="generate the distribution">
    <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib"/>

    <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the java-assignment-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/lib/java-assignment-${DSTAMP}.jar" basedir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean"
        description="clean up">
    <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Then I ran `ant dist` in the shell and finally executed:

```
java -cp dist/lib/java-assignment-20200901.jar main.Main
```

to run the application.

Both the compilation and the execution runs fine.

I used OpenJDK 11.0.8 2020-07-14.

Please let me know if any of this helps.

Edit 2:

I put the working code on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/kbotor/docker-gui-test). You can ignore the `Dockerfile` and references to Docker, the rest I already explained.

Comment: Please add code for Finance_Period  to your question.

Comment: There is none yet, i still have to get to it

Comment: To be clear - it's an empty class without any metgods or fields or the class does not exist at all?

Comment: The class is there but there is nothing absolutely nothing there

Comment: Is it in package `main` or `Main`? Wha are you using to build and run this code?

Comment: There is nothing there yet, im suing netbeans

Comment: Wait, I don't understand what you mean by build.xml file? I Don't even know where that is? and I did fix the error I saw it earlier

Comment: `build.xml` is a build file for a Java build tool called Ant: https://ant.apache.org/. I had to build the project somehow and I wasn't going to call `javac` directly from command line. I understand that Netbeans has built-in support for Ant.

Comment: I have no idea, i have honestly never heard of that

Comment: As far as I can tell Netbeans 12 needs either Maven, Gradle or Ant to build the project - so you had to specify some build tool.