# Is there a way to make an array truly private in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, encapsulation, access-specifier

If I do something like

```
private int[] myPrivateArray;
```

and have a getter that returns the array, then the array contents can be modified from outside the class, which sort of defeats the purpose of making it private.

Comment: if you don't want to change the content from outside return copy of your private array object. use deep cloning or shallow cloning accordingly.

Comment: "If I ... have a getter that returns the array" - *why do you have that*? You do not need a getter for everything.

Comment: Defensive copies? Same way any mutable state-if you don't want to expose it you need to return copies or immutable objects.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is.

Firstly, don't provide a getter for that array if you don't have to. If you MUST provide a getter, then pass a copy, not the private variable.

Secondly (which has been overlooked so far), make sure the JVM `SecurityManager` is set up to stop [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java%22reflection%22).

Answer (score 5):

You can provide setters, getters for the specific index elements of the array, much like what List implementations do. As for returning it from a function, you can copy the array, and pass the copy instead. Rather than passing reference to your array, you pass reference to a copy of your array.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can return a copy of the array:

```
public int[]getMyArray(){
    return myPrivateArray.clone();
}
```

Alternatively, you can provide a getter to access individual elements of the array:

```
public int getMyArray(int index){
    return myPrivateArray.get(index);
}
```

Finally, if you'd like to avoid copying but insist on returning all the elements at once, you can return an unmodifiable list view of your array:

```
public class MyClass{
    private Object[]myPrivateArray;

    private List<Object>myArrayView=Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(myPrivateArray));

    public List<Object>getMyArrayView(){
        return myArrayView;
    }
}
```

Although this is slightly more complicated with an array of primitives:

```
public class MyClass{
    private int[]myPrivateArray;

    private List<Integer>myArrayView=new AbstractList<Integer>(){
        @Override public int size(){
            return myPrivateArray.length;
        }
        @Override public Integer get(int index){
            return myPrivateArray[index]
        }
    }
    public List<Integer>getMyArrayView(){
        return myArrayView;
    }
}
```