# Attempt parsing unknown object types

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-studio

I'm using an SDK and am trying to extract data from an object (Merchant) that's being retrieved, and although the class has some useful methods for returning specific fields, I can clearly see more information available by setting a watch in Android Studio and checking that at a breakpoint.

[image: Android Studio unknown object fields]

I'm trying to get all of this data out in String form, and I was wondering how. Using "merchant.toString()" does get some information out, but it looks as if the text I can't access is the part within "mMap".

I can spot the words "Bundle" and "ArrayMap" in the preview, and I have tried to read through the class in the java file from the SDK, but I'm not making much sense of it so far.

How can I read from these fields that Android Studio can preview?

EDIT: [Link to the objects class](https://github.com/clover/clover-android-sdk/blob/master/clover-android-sdk/src/main/java/com/clover/sdk/v1/merchant/Merchant.java)

Comment: Please [edit]  to show the Merchant class

Comment: @cricket_007 I have updated with a link to the class.

Comment: The mMap is private to the class, you cannot directly access it. What exactly do you need from it?

Comment: I'd like to grab the "employees" array. Would the only solution be to edit the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `data` field is private, you can try to retrieve information from private field using java reflection. For example, like it shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java).