# Xtext: Filtering content assist proposals using type system

Tags: autocomplete, xtext, type-systems, content-assist

I've implemented my own type system by using Validator class.
Now I want to have only valid proposals when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>-ing (currently it suggests also invalid things).

For example:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
String s = "something";

a = //at this point, the auto completion should suggest only b, not s.
    //Of course that picking up s causes an error (I implemented my type system that way).
```

Is it possible to implement from my inherited `ui.contentassist.{}ProposalProvider` class?

Thanks.

**Update**

Following Christian's advice, I found it easier to call super.complete_something from the inherited {}ProposalProvider class and then remove irrelevant proposals from acceptor.delegate.proposals.
Pay attention that proposals is a private field but it's [easy to overcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java).

Comment: what about factoring the typesystem out to a utility class and use it inside the proposal provider?

Comment: Can you please elaborate why a utility class would be helpful? I already have a function named typecheck(EObject eo) in Validator class.  This function calls to a utility class with a lot of typecheck(Class C) functions, where C extends EObject (C is some grammar rule).

Comment: so if you already have a utility why no call it in the proposal provider? i thought you have a utility like `getType()` or `getExpectedType`. the proposal provider will call lookupCrossReference somewhere in call hierarchy. you can call it with a custom filter

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out. Another thing - when I do Ctrl+Space I get irrelevant proposals of terminals from the grammar. I overrided every function in AbstractProposalProvider with an empty implementation but I still get these proposals. How can I completely remove these proposals so I can start from scratch?

Comment: Sure you did not miss stuff eg completeKeyword or completeXyz

Comment: Okay I see now. I extended Abstract{MyDSL}ProposalProvider instead of AbstractContentProposalProvider. Should I extend AbstractContentProposalProvider and copy things from Abstract{MyDSL}ProposalProvider when needed? I'm not sure what is the relation between these two classes.

Comment: Just leave it with the default

Comment: Thank you very much. Now terminals are filtered.

For future readers: you should extend Abstract{MyDSL}ProposalProvider (the default) and then override completeKeyword from AbstractContentProposalProvider. Pay attention to the parameters (different from the Abstract{MyDSL}ProposalProvider functions).

Comment: @ChristianDietrich, Sorry for bothering you, but I'm trying to filter lookupCrossReference. Do you mean to filter one of its parameters? If so, is it assignment.getTerminal() or context? Otherwise (makes more sense), should I filter the outcome of lookupCrossReference? It's a void function so I'm not quite sure what to do.

Comment: Follow the code that is generated . It will indirectly call a method that has a predicate as param . You can be build the same call methodidontknowwithoutlookingatcode(param1,     Params, your predicate , moreparams)