# Java - Access Class Variable

Tags: java, methods, class-variables

I was wondering how I would access a `Class` variable from within a method where I have gotten the `Class` as an argument. Like this:

Method

```
public void someMethod(Class<? extends SomeClass> clazz) {
     System.out.println(clazz.var);
}
```

`Class`

```
class SomeClass {
    public static String var = "Hello World!";
}
```

The part `class.var` doesn't work as expected. If an extending `Class` changes the value of `var` I want this value to be written out instead.

**EDIT:** This question is not answered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-to-read-the-value-of-a-private-field-from-a-different-class-in-java) question. I need to access a `class` variable not a `private` one.

Comment: As a side note, `class` cannot be used as a variable name. It is a keyword in the language.

Comment: @Logan you are absolutely right!

Comment: Popular choices are `clazz` and `klass`.

Comment: @Logan You don't have any ideas as how to resolve my problem?

Comment: Look at the questions that yours was marked as a duplicate of. You’ll have to use the `Field` class and `Class`’s `getDeclaredField()` method.

Comment: @Logan But what if I don't have an instance of the `Class` and only the `Class` itself?

Comment: You can invoke the method by coding `ClassName.class.getDeclaredField("fieldName")`. `.class` gives you access to the class’s `Class` instance.

Comment: @Logan I'm sorry but I don't understand. Would you mind writing a full answer to my post?

Comment: I’m not able to anymore. Read the answers marked above. They outline exactly what you need to do.