# Java How to access private static member of class

Tags: java, reflection

Hi may I know how to access private static member outside Java classes?

I want to check if a value is set correctly.

Comment: You mean while debugging?

Comment: "*I want to check if a value is set correctly.*" Don't use reflection, it breaks encapsulation. If you need to check the value, introduce a (possibly package-private) getter for the field.

Comment: I mean while testing @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: You don't. If it's private it's not meant to be accessed. Or by providing a getter.

Comment: @Turing85 I see, thanks

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I see, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(All necessary alerts about using reflection.)*

Using reflection

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
//      Class<A> clazz = A.class;            // if you know the class statically i.e. at compile time
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("A"); // if you know class name dynamically i.e. at runtime
        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("x");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println(field.getInt(null)); // 10
    }
}

class A {
    private static int x = 10;
}
```

`null` is because the field is static, so there is no need in an instance of `A`.

[How to read the value of a private field from a different class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-to-read-the-value-of-a-private-field-from-a-different-class-in-java)

Comment: `field.setAccessible(true);` is a crucial bit for accessing private members, thanks @Dmytro

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but I've heard that PowerMock is capable of testing private methods as well.
https://github.com/powermock/powermock