# How to fetch variables from a third party class without in-build methods

Tags: java, class, instance

I am using a third party Java class to fetch an instance of the class. However, only a few variables can be fetched using respective methods.
I can see other variables when I print the instance and I would like to fetch some of them. Is there a Java way to do that.

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-to-read-the-value-of-a-private-field-from-a-different-class-in-java

Answer (score 2):

As it was pointed out in comment. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1196207/11733759).
And use reflection in this way:

```
Field f = thirdPartyObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("hiddenString"); //NoSuchFieldException
f.setAccessible(true);
String hiddenString = (String) f.get(thirdPartyObject); //IllegalAccessException
```