# Why can't I access a private method with the Java Reflection API?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to access a private method, but it doesn't let me to, and throws the exception. How can I avoid the exception? I've tried a lot of other questions, but they all just point to using setAccessible(true), which I'm already using right now.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Reflection {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            //Get class instance
            ReflectionExamples re = new ReflectionExamples();
            Class<?> c = re.getClass();
            System.out.println("Class name is " + c.getName());
            //Get constructor of class
            Constructor<?> cons = c.getConstructor();
            System.out.println("Constructor name is " + cons.getName());
            System.out.println("List of methods are:");
            //Iterate all methods
            Method[] methods = c.getMethods();
            for (Method method : methods) {
                System.out.println(method.getName());
            }
            //Desired method to call
            Method call = c.getDeclaredMethod("e");
            //Unlock the private Method
            call.setAccessible(true);
            //Invoke the Method
            call.invoke(re);
            //Desired method to call
            Method call2 = c.getDeclaredMethod("a");
            //Invoke the method
            call2.invoke(c);
        } catch(Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}

class ReflectionExamples {
    
    private String string = "String222222";
    public int i = 0;
    
    public ReflectionExamples() {
        string = "String";
    }
    
    private void e() {
        System.out.println("Char entered is not valid.");
    }
    
    public void f(char a) {
         System.out.println("awojiewfihuerhkuah");
    }
    
    public void a() {
         System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

And I get:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
```

Comment: How do you *run* this code?

Comment: That works for me. Last call should be `call2.invoke(re);` not `call2.invoke(c);`

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-to-read-the-value-of-a-private-field-from-a-different-class-in-java

Comment: Do you use security policies?

Comment: You have a security manager installed. I don't know why, but by default, a SecurityManager denies access to such a permission.