# Access original (user) message text in a LuisIntent method (MBF version 3)

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to access the original message in a `LuisIntent` method in a `LuisModel` class I am using in a Microsoft Bot Framework (version 3) C# project. However, I can't seem to figure it out myself, nor do any suggestions made in [a related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482531/how-do-you-get-to-the-original-message-text-in-a-microsoft-bot-framework-luisint) work (because this concerns MBF version 1).

I tried commenting on [a related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/73), without success.

Does anyone know how to get the user message that fired the method?

Comment: Luis returns the actual message in query, so check args.query. The args is all json format, you can easily log it to see what coming from luis and what should be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update (08/09/2016)

Since latest release (3.2.0), thanks for the commit (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/commit/f156a60880e86f7b853b1f94a5546386436ac3d0)

**Now we are able to get the activity directly from the intent handler**

Sample code

```
public async Task Test(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> origin, LuisResult result)
```

---

## Original answer (05/08/2016)

You can have a property to store the origin activity and assign it in `MessageReceived`

```
public class YourDialog : LuisDialog<string>
{    
    [NonSerialized]
    private IMessageActivity _originActivity;

    internal YourDialog()
    {
    }

    [LuisIntent("IntentionConstant.Empty")]
    public async Task HandleLuisResult(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            // you can access _originActivity here

        }
        catch (Exception ex) when(ex is ApplicationException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex is TaskCanceledException)
        {
        }
    }

    protected override async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item)
    {
        _originActivity = await item;
        await base.MessageReceived(context, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I've been looking for this for ages! :)

Comment: @MartinKearn there's a better way to do it now, check my update