# How to access Session Timeout value in Asp.Net Core MVC 1.0 (aka MVC 6 RC1)?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In Asp.Net Core MVC 1.0 (MVC 6 RC1) the session timeout period is specified when session support is added in the `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs like so:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.CookieName = "Session";
        });
```

My question is this: elsewhere in the application how can this `IdleTimeout` value be accessed?

I would expect to find it as a property off of the HttpContext.Session object but it does not appear to be there.  I've searched high and low and this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a private field inside of the `DistributedSession` class. So at the moment, you can't get it. Session seems to be missing a lot of properties from the old [HttpSessionState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate(v=vs.110).aspx) class, but I can't find anything pointing to what the reason may be (there might be a good one!).

You *could* get it with reflection, but it's pretty gnarly. The example below uses [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3303182/4270650).

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var value = GetInstanceField(typeof(DistributedSession), HttpContext.Session, "_idleTimeout");
    return View();
}
```

I would recommend storing the value in a configuration file or an `internal class` somewhere.

Comment: +1 for recommending storing the value elsewhere and using it to set the `options.IdleTimeout`.  This wasn't the way I wanted to solve the problem but if it's the only alternative to reflecting a private member var than it's the better of two hacks.