# How to access TemplateContent.RootType

Tags: c#

In the VS 2015 watch window it shows a RootType property on the TemplateContent; however the compiler doesn't seem to know about it.  Does anyone know how to access it from code?
Thanks in avance,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/TemplateContent.cs,2ef50935af4f45ae), that property in `internal` and not accessible outside of the source assembly.  The only way you can access it outside of the assembly is through [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303126).

I would first look for a public property that gets you what you need, or look through the documentation to see if there's a public method that would work for you.  Internal implementations can change in the future, which may break your code without notice.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Thanks for the reminder of the reference source.