# How do I obtain the value of a private field of some metadata?

Tags: c#, metadata, field, private

I'm using a NuGet Package called **DevExpress.Xpo** and its *DataStorePool* class has a private *int* called *connections*. I need to somehow use its value in another class, but the DataStorePool class is locked as "metadata", so I can't set the *int* to *public* nor create a method that returns it. What can I do to obtain the value of the *int*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an extension method to do it.
It can look like that:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
string c = foo.GetFieldValue<string>("_bar");
```

And the way to create it:

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions {
    public static T GetFieldValue<T>(this object obj, string name) {
        // Set the flags so that private and public fields from instances will be found
        var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var field = obj.GetType().GetField(name, bindingFlags);
        return (T)field?.GetValue(obj);
    }
}
```

OR

You can use BindingFlags.NonPublic and BindingFlags.Instance flags

```
FieldInfo[] fields = myType.GetFields(
                         BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                         BindingFlags.Instance);
```

OR

[You could read how to get it with using reflection here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303126/how-to-get-the-value-of-private-field-using-reflection/3303182#3303182)