# To access private arrays, classes are double-wrapped

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, accessibility, private

Array variable included and class in class. I know how to use general reflection, but the class is duplicated and the intermediate variable is in the form of an array. Can you help me solve this problem?

```
using System.Reflection;
using space1;
using space2;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace space1
{
    public class BigClass
    {
        BigClass.SmallClass[] CustomArrays;

        public BigClass()
        {
            this.CustomArrays = new BigClass.SmallClass[2];
            CustomArrays[0] = new SmallClass(17);
            CustomArrays[1] = new SmallClass(18);
        }

        private class SmallClass
        {
            private int MyGoal;
            public SmallClass(int a)
            {
                MyGoal = a;
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace space2
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            BigClass a = new BigClass();

            FieldInfo fieldinfo1 = typeof(BigClass).GetField("CustomArrays", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);


            Console.WriteLine();
            //Console.WriteLine(fieldinfo2.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to finally get the MyGoal value of space1 and return the number 18 by making the value +1. Do I have to access Field first and then access Field again? I tried GetType(), GetTypeof(), etc. after I approached the first Field, but I couldn't access the next Field. Also, since it's declared Array, how do I tell if it's [0] or [1]?
If print out the field with the code written above, it will only be displayed as CustomArray. How can I use this separately by Array?

Comment: Why try to use reflection?  Add methods or change those private fields to public properties.

Comment: This is because there is a separate file that can't modify. This is the sample code that simplified the problem.

Comment: Trying to modify the internal state of an object from a third party is playing with fire.  The third party could change the internal implementation and break your reflection code.  Is your issue an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem#:~:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20a,(Y%20or%20Why%3F).)?

Comment: I admit it's playing with fire, but I'll have to go back a long way to get another way. I posted a question because I only need to manipulate some variables within the protected object. I didn't post a question to say something like really need this or not? I just want to know how to deal with Reflection and how to use it in more difficult situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing [the advice I gave you last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77875641) didn't help, seeing that you've reposted. It's still a [really bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3303139/1043380) to do this - if you need access to some data, make it public. If it's not public, there's generally a good reason why it's not.

With this structure

```
public class Parent
{
    private Child[] childRefs;

    public Parent()
    {
        childRefs = [new Child(5), new Child(6), new Child(7)];
    }

    private class Child
    {
        private int innerValue;

        public Child(int value)
        {
            innerValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You can get the values of `innerValue` by using reflection twice. No need to use the type `Child` directly in your code.

```
var parent = new Parent();

FieldInfo childRefField = typeof(Parent).GetField("childRefs", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)!;
IEnumerable childRefFieldValues = (childRefField.GetValue(parent) as IEnumerable)!;

foreach (var childRefFieldValue in childRefFieldValues)
{
    FieldInfo childInternalField = childRefFieldValue.GetType().GetField("innerValue", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)!;
    int? childInternalValue = childInternalField.GetValue(childRefFieldValue) as int?;
    Console.WriteLine(childInternalValue);
}
```

Arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>` as well as `IEnumerable`, the non-generic version, which this solution uses. `childRefFieldValue` is treated as an `object`, so you can continue using reflection from there.

This prints 5, 6, 7.

Comment: Smart response to a silly question. Posting again was because my question was closed as redundant. Thank you so much for your help.