# Getting non-public properties of a type via reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

How can I get non-public properties of a type via reflection?

Comment: What do you need that for? My first impulse is: Rethink your design.

Comment: Yes. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95910/find-a-private-field-with-reflection - i think it has all that you need

Comment: I've tried Type.GetProperties(). But it returns only public properties, but I need internal as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Specify `BindingFlags.NonPublic` in your call to `GetProperties()`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var f = new Foo();
        foreach (var fi in f.GetType().GetProperties(
                               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fi);
        }
    }       
}

public class Foo
{
    private string Prop { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

try this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) for details.

Comment: This will return an empty array, you also need to specify BindingFlags.Instance or BindingFlags.Static.