# how to access private variable from one class to another?

Tags: .net

In class A I am have a private variable that I want to access it from another class. Is it possible? Give me the solution.

Comment: If you give more information about why you need to access it and why it is declared private etc, you'll probably get better answers.

Comment: if it were possible why privates will exist ?

Answer (score 2):

The private variable is supposed to be private, so there's no direct way to do this.  There are a couple of things you could do.

1. Expose the private item via an accessor (requires the code)
2. Use reflection to poke around in the object and find it (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95910/find-a-private-field-with-reflection))

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access it from "outside" you will have to make it public. But better would be to wrap a property around it. Then you could even give readonly access.

```
public class MyClass
{
   private int myPrivateInt;

   public int PublicInt
   {
     get { return myPrivateInt; }
     set { myPrivateInt = value; } // or remove this line for readonly access
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the private var in modern .NET versions. ;)

`public class MyClass
{

   public int PublicInt
   {
     get;
     set; // or remove this line for readonly access
   }
}`

Comment: @Alex - I know, I was just showing how you could publish an existing local variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access a private variable from another class.

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of the "private" access modifier is to prevent this. I think you're looking for moving the variabele to a shared base class or using the "internal" access modifier to restrict accessibility to the classes in the same assembly.

If you really want to access it you can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx), but that's something you should try as a last resort. For example, if you use it to access private things in a 3th party library future versions of that lib (with the same public API) can break your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you could access them, then there wouldn't not be any point in making them private.

However, in practice, **get, set** are usually implemented if you need access to such members.

Answer (score -1):

Um...it is called `private` for a reason. Make it `public`?