# Getting access to IsActive property in Sitecore

Tags: c#, properties, sitecore

Within the Sitecore User Manager it is possible to either enable or disable specific users.
I have searched a lot around the Internet to find a way to access this property programatically in C#, just as you can access the built-in property IsAdministrator like this:

```
Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.IsAdministrator
```

But I can't seem to find anything close to it!

So I would like to know if it is possible to access a property like `IsActive`.

Thaks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default providers, Sitecore just uses standard ASP.NET Membership.  The Sitecore API doesn't appear to expose this property, but it's very easy to get at:

```
System.Web.Security.MembershipUser membershipuser = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(username);
```

Now check membershipuser.IsLockedOut.

Comment: Thanks, that's half the answer! How du I set the property to a specific boolean value?

Comment: I found what I was looking for! I just hade to set the IsApproved = false/true

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on a version 6.x installation, I believe that the Profile property is enumerable (and indexable using ["IsActive"]).

See the Security API Cookbook on SDN for more details: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/security_api_cookbook_a4.pdf (chapter 3.3 for example).

Answer (score -1):

if you want to access private properties, this could be useful

[Find a private field with Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95910/find-a-private-field-with-reflection)

Comment: I do not think you understand the question