# Alter Column Heading Text DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

As title says. My code is not working, and I am not sure why. I've looked at other sources and they seem to suggest what I am trying to do below via code. Anyone have any ideas?

I also tried `.Columns(0).Name = New Heading Name`

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    With DataGridView1
        .DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.DodgerBlue
        .DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.White
        .ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue
        .ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite
        .DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Calibri", 12, FontStyle.Regular)

        .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "Employee ID"
        .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Account Number"
        .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Last Name"
        .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "First Name"
        .Columns(4).HeaderCell.Value = "Company"
        .Columns(5).HeaderCell.Value = "Beginning Date"
        .Columns(6).HeaderCell.Value = "Ending Date"
    End With
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using data-binding to a type and auto-generated columns you can do something like this:

```
[DisplayName("Header Name")]
public string fieldName{get;set;}
```

In another way, as you said, you should use:

```
grid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Header Name";
```

But here something else I did not try. Also try something like this:

```
myDataGrid.TableStyles[0].GridColumnStyles[0].HeaderText = "Header Name"
```

But as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829570/set-columns-width-in-a-datagrid-using-compact-framework) answer says, you should do something like this:

```
dataGrid1.TableStyles.Clear();
DataGridTableStyle tableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
tableStyle.MappingName = t.TableName;
foreach (DataColumn item in t.Columns)
{
    DataGridTextBoxColumn tbcName = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
    tbcName.Width = 100;
    tbcName.MappingName = item.ColumnName;
    tbcName.HeaderText = item.ColumnName;
    tableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(tbcName);
 }
 dataGrid1.TableStyles.Add(tableStyle);
```

Comment: I did not. Do I need to add a TableStyle to my grid view?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829570/set-columns-width-in-a-datagrid-using-compact-framework :)

Comment: Thanks. The columns(0).HeaderText = " Name " did not work for me for some reason, still.

Comment: I haven't found a working solution for my needs yet.