# Set the precision for double/float/decimal in System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, precision

How can I set the precision for a data column that holds double, float or decimal numbers in a System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid?

For DataGridView there is [How to format a column with number decimal with max and min in DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229590/how-to-format-a-column-with-number-decimal-with-max-and-min-in-datagridview), for example.

I want `0.0100000001` to be displayed as `0.01`, for example, which would be precision of 2 digits after the decimal mark. I want to avoid them looking like this, where float and double use the scientific notation:

[image]

The code I used to fill the table is:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("double");
table.Columns.Add("float");
table.Columns.Add("decimal");
table.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(double);
table.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(float);
table.Columns[2].DataType = typeof(decimal);
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0.00000000000423, 0.00000000000423, 0.00000000000423 });
dataGrid1.DataSource = table;
```

*Note: I know DataGrid is obsolete, but I'm dealing with legacy code, please don't comment to tell me to use DataGridView - it doesn't help me.*

Comment: Do you want to change the actual precision of the values, or the format in which they're displayed? In either case, what result are you looking for?

Comment: @stuartd I want to format how they are displayed. The data source itself shouldn't be changed. I'm looking for an equivalent of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229590/how-to-format-a-column-with-number-decimal-with-max-and-min-in-datagridview

Comment: So you can [get a reference to the column and set the format](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/ColumnStyles.aspx)?

Comment: @stuartd Thanks for the pointer. I had been trying to use `GridColumnStyles` but `DataGridColumnStyle` didn't have a `Format` property. It seems `DataGridTextBoxColumn` is derived from `DataGridColumnStyle` and I should explicitly cast to it.

Comment: @stuartd Thanks, it worked. I've posted the solution I found.

Answer (score 2):

I've derived my solution from @stuartd comments. I needed to set the `Format` column [of the current table style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39832554/492336) for the DataGrid.

```
/// <summary>
///  Getting and setting the column widths of a DataGrid is not easy at all.
///  This helper class handles it, including saving and restoring from a string.
/// </summary>
static class DataGridColumnWidthExtensions
{
    /// Get the current table style.
    public static DataGridTableStyle GetCurrentTableStyle(this DataGrid grid)
    {
        // DataGrid holds the current grid table style into a private field called myGridTable.
        // The field points to the "default" table style even if TableStyles is empty. The 
        // default table style is also private/internal.
        // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39832554/492336 and 
        // https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGrid.cs,211.
        FieldInfo[] fields = grid.GetType().GetFields(
                     BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                     BindingFlags.Instance);

        return (DataGridTableStyle)fields.First(item => item.Name == "myGridTable").GetValue(grid);
    }
}
```

Then we can just iterate the GridColumnStyles and set the Format property for each numeric column:

```
var tableStyle = dataGrid1.GetCurrentTableStyle();
for (int ii = 0; ii < table.Columns.Count; ii++)
{
    var columnStyle = tableStyle.GridColumnStyles[ii] as DataGridTextBoxColumn;
    if (columnStyle == null)
    {
        // DataGridTextBoxColumn inherits DataGridColumnStyle but in theory
        // a column might be of some other type deriving from DataGridColumnStyle.
        continue;
    }

    var columnType = table.Columns[ii].DataType;
    if (columnType != typeof(double) && columnType != typeof(float) && columnType != typeof(decimal))
    {
        // We set the format only for numeric columns.
        continue;
    }

    // 2 digits after the decimal mark.
    columnStyle.Format = "N2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find Updated ans

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("double");
table.Columns.Add("float");
table.Columns.Add("decimal");
dataGrid1.DataSource = table;
table.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(double);
table.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(float);
table.Columns[2].DataType = typeof(decimal);
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0.00000000000423, 0.00000000000423, 0.00000000000423 });
```

always first bind datagrid then format the column

Comment: How does that answer my question? Or is it meant to be a comment? What does "ans" in "Updated ans" mean?

Comment: The code doesn't change anything. It doesn't change the precision and doesn't answer my question. Besides, I'm not formatting the columns, I'm setting the DataType which is a DataTable property and does not depend on the DataGrid. Your change is pointless.