# C# : Displaying field metadata using System.Reflection.GetFields()

Tags: c#, system.reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find a private field with Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95910/find-a-private-field-with-reflection)

I am trying to display a class's field names using the System.Reflection.GetFields() method.

Problem is it only works when the fields are declared as "public". 
For example :

```
class Element
{
    private String id;
    private string a;
    private string b;
    private int c;
    private Dictionary<String, String> dict;

    public Element(String id)
    {
        this.id= id;
    }}
```

When I try calling the System.Reflection.GetFields() method, it doesn't work (it returns an empty array). However, if I change the visibility of the fields to "public", it works..

Anyone know how I can get it to work without having to make it public?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
```

UPDATE:
Here is what going under scene when you call GetFields without parameter:

```
public FieldInfo[] GetFields()
{
   return this.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
}
```

So, as you can see, private fields are not returned by default.

Btw here is description of [GetFields()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3.aspx) method from msdn:

> Returns all the *public fields* of the current Type. Return Value: An array of
>   FieldInfo objects representing all the public fields defined for the
>   current Type. -or- An empty array of type FieldInfo, if no public fields
>   are defined for the current Type.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var fieldinfo = typeof(Element).GetField("field name", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                             BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Answer (score 1):

The GetFields method returns only the *public* fields.
If you want it to return both private and public fields use this:

```
c.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Public);
```

You must specify **BindingFlags.Instance** or **BindingFlags.Static** along with BindingFlags.Public or BindingFlags.NonPublic or no members will be returned.

Take a look at msdn for more information:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx)