# Access private fields

Tags: c#, .net, private

Is it possible to get or set private fields?

I want to get `System.Guid.c`. Is there a way to access it or should I just copy the code from the strut and make the fields public?

Comment: Changed it, but its just System.Guid anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find a private field with Reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95910/find-a-private-field-with-reflection)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use reflection as suggested by Quantic Programming

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var field= typeof (Guid).GetField("_c", BindingFlags.NonPublic |BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);
var value = field.GetValue(guid);
```

Although if you are okay with first converting the guid to a byte array, I might suggest:

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var c = BitConverter.ToInt16(guid.ToByteArray(), 6);
```

The latter approach avoids using reflection.

**Edit**

You mention needing to be able to set the value as well, you can still avoid reflection:

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var guidBytes = guid.ToByteArray();

// get value
var c = BitConverter.ToInt16(guidBytes, 6);

// set value
Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(c), 0, guidBytes, 6, sizeof(Int16));
var modifiedGuid = new Guid(guidBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it will be using the first unless there's a negative to using reflection?

Comment: @godzcheater - as mentioned by drf, using reflection to access private members is generally bad practise. You are using the internals of a class to access data. Where possible you should always try to stick to the public api. Reflection of private members will require a full trust environment and has the potential to be brittle code as the internals of the class may change over time.

Answer (score 6):

You should try [System.Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx). Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace AccessPrivateField
{
    class foo
    {
        public foo(string str)
        {
            this.str = str;
        }
        private string str;
        public string Get()
        {
            return this.str;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foo bar = new foo("hello");
            Console.WriteLine(bar.Get());
            typeof(foo).GetField("str", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(bar, "changed");
            Console.WriteLine(bar.Get());
            //output:
            //hello
            //changed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just note that if you're running Silverlight, you won't be able to access the private members.  You didn't specify that you were, but just in case.

Comment: Why not? Do you mean you can't access Silverlight's internal data, or you can't do it at all when under Silverlight?

Comment: With Silverlight, the runtime prevents you from accessing non-public data via reflection as it's a security issue.  For example, some of the file I/O code is in the runtime, but you can normally only access it through special, managed means which do not violate security concerns.  If you could use reflection to get down to the nitty-gritty of hidden file I/O, then by just browsing to a malicious Silverlight page could wipe/read your computers files at will.

Comment: Oh, a security issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can have an extension method to get any private field of any type:

```
public static T GetFieldValue<T>(this object obj, string name) {
    var field = obj.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    return (T)field?.GetValue(obj);
}
```

And then access a private field of an arbitrary type:

```
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
Int16 c = id.GetFieldValue<Int16>("_c");
```

Answer (score 3):

While it's possible to do this with reflection, it may be easier to simply retrieve `c` from `System.Guid.ToByteArray()`.

```
byte[] guid = guid.ToByteArray();
short c = (short)((guid[7] << 8) | guid[6]);
```

Since this approach uses public and documented methods, it is less subject to change between versions.  (In general, relying on private implementation details should be avoided, since these details can change from version to version.)