# An interview riddle: accessing a private data member

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I recently had an interview with C# questions. One of them I cannot find an answer to.

I was given a class, looks like this:

```
public class Stick
{
    private int m_iLength;
    public int Length
    {
        get
        {
            return m_iLength;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
            {
                m_iLength = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, a main class was given

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stick stick = new Stick();
}
```

The task was to add code to the main that will cause `m_iLength` in the Stick class to be negative (and it was stressed out that it can be done).

I seem to miss something. The data member is private, and as far as I know the get and set function are by value for type int, so I do not see how this can be done.

Comment: reflection maybe?

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862747/access-private-fields

Comment: @Sayse in C# you can't override class members unless they are declared "virtual" (contrast with Java for example). Reflection is the only way I can see (short of modifying the underlying IL, or using unsafe code to modify the memory backing iLength - not even sure if that last one is possible!)

Comment: Is it possible to override a non-virtual property or access the private members of the super class?

Comment: Even if you could override the property, you could not set the field value in it because it's private.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflection is always the most direct:

```
var type = typeof(Stick);
var field = type.GetField("m_iLength", BindingFlags.NonPublic |BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);
field.SetValue(stick, -1);
Console.WriteLine(stick.Length);
```

Explanation:

The first line gets the `Type` object for `Stick`, so we can get the private fields later on.

The second line gets the field that we want to set by its name. Note that the binding flags are required or `field` will be `null`.

And the third line gives the field a negative value.