# InkCanvas with time information

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, instrumentation, inkcanvas

I'm using Microsoft Ink Canvas for WPF and I need to change the configuration to get the time informationfor.

With winforms and MSInk I do that by using the InkCollector object. With InkCanvas I realized that there's also a embeeded InkCollector object but no way to access to it. It is necessary to access to it in order to instruct  InkCollector to get time data via setting DesiredPacketDescription attribute.

In MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd187712.aspx) shows a protected member _inkCollector, but, I  cannot find it using instrumentation  ([Find a private field with Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95910/find-a-private-field-with-reflection)).

Perharps there's another solution?

Thanks in advance,
Ivan.

Answer (score 0):

The `_inkCollector` field is `protected`. You can access it if you extend InkCanvas:

```
class MyInkCanvas:InkCanvas
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is not working. It looks like the documentation of the InkCanvas does not fit with the binaries.