# Can't get field through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Here is my class:

```
public static class Root
{
    private static readonly NestedOne nestedOne;

    static Root()
    {
        nestedOne = new NestedOne();
    }

    class NestedOne
    {
        private string FindMe = "blabla";
    }
}
```

I need get that field that called 'FindMe' through the Root. I successfully get the instance of NestedOne:

```
var nestedOne = typeof(Root).GetField("nestedOne", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

But can't get further:

```
var fields = nestedOne.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic);  // there is empty
```

Please help me

Comment: This is also helpful: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95910/find-a-private-field-with-reflection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `nestedOne` is an instance of [`FieldInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.FieldInfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. Calling `nestedOne.GetType()` will give you an instance of `Type` that represents the `FieldInfo` type.
3. Since `Type` has no fields, you get an empty collection.

What you want to do is use the [FieldType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.fieldtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property instead of calling `.GetType()`

```
nestedOne.FieldType.GetFields(...)
```

You also need to specify the `BindingFlags.Instance` flag for instance fields.

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kZxvMp

Comment: Oh I see. but i'm confused, how can i set the value on that field?

Comment: I got it: var v = nestedOne.GetValue(null); f.SetValue(v, "123");

Answer (score 3):

The field you are looking for is an instance field, you need to include that category in your search by specifying the `BindingFlags.Instance` flag

```
GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using  [GetNestedTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/493t6h7t.aspx)

```
Type[] myTypeArray = myType.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN documentation you must specify BindingFlags.Instance
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx