# Access field _invocationList by reflection

Tags: c#, events, visual-studio-2013, reflection, delegates

Is it possible to access from outside of the class private field _invocationList using reflections ?

[image]

I have tried to

```
var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;

Type type = common.GetType();

var myEvent = type.GetEvent("OnTransformerTypeChanged");

var myfields = myEvent.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic |BindingFlags.Instance);
```

or

```
var myfields = myEvent.GetType().GetField("_invocationList", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: Yes probably, what have you tried? [ask].. also a screenshot is hard to see (some cant see it at all) instead, describe the problem.

Comment: Yes you can. But.. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find a private field with Reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95910/find-a-private-field-with-reflection)

Comment: @Sinatr - When a work policy blocks images, no amount of clicking will make it readable