# How to call Method of Private Property using Reflection in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection, propertyinfo

I have some problems with my project.

I want to call one method from `private` Property like `private clsBUS_DEMO prop_DEMO`

`clsBUS_DEMO` has a Method, which Name is `public void SayHello()`.

This is my code

```
PropertyInfo p = this.GetType().GetProperty("SayHello");
```

`p` is `null` because program can't find `prop_DEMO`

Can anybody help me about this?

Comment: SayHello() isn't a property, it's a method.  The property that you are after is prop_DEMO, which will return a clsBUS_DEMO instance, and you can call SayHello() on that

Comment: Yes, it's Method. 
Now i have like this
`PropertyInfo p = this.GetType().GetProperty("prop_DEMO");`
`MethodInfo method = p.GetType().GetMethod("SayHello");`

Comment: But it's still return null

Comment: Just to confirm, you're making this call from a method within the clsBUS_DEMO class?

Comment: GetProperty() defaults to only returning public properties, so you need to change your call to this.GetType.GetProperty("prop_DEMO", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance ).

Comment: @TrươngLong can you write code for clsBUS_DEMO class and the class that is property is used in?

Comment: yes. I wanna call a public method from clsBUS_DEMO.

Comment: @Arvin  I take a photo use my language
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxrNWDKN5N6rWHVMQmdJZDBMcWc&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clsBUS_DEMO prop_DEMO` is not a property, it's a `Field`. You need to use GetFields to get it and also since it's `private` you need to pass `BindingFlags.NonPublic` and `BindingFlags.Instance`.

Here is a sample of how you should do it

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        Foo foo = (Foo)bar.GetType().GetField("a", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(bar);
        foo.GetType().GetMethod("ShowMessage").Invoke(foo,new object[] { });
    }
    public class Bar
    {
        private Foo a;
        public Bar()
        {
            a = new Foo();
        }
    }
    public class Foo
    {
        public void ShowMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a method of private property? Not sure if I understood what you want, it would be useful to have the class that represent you object. Do you mean call a property that returns an object and then call a method of that object?

Anyways, I think there's a lot information out there about that topic, for example: 
[How do I use reflection to invoke a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135443/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-invoke-a-private-method)
[Find a private field with Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95910/find-a-private-field-with-reflection)

```
class MyClass1
{
    public MyClass1()
    {
        Prop = new MyClass2();
    }

    public MyClass2 Prop { get; set; } 
}

class MyClass2
{
    private int Test()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var obj = new MyClass1();
    var obj2 = obj.Prop;

    var propInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Prop");

    var obj2Reflection = propInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
    var dynMethod = obj2.GetType().GetMethod("Test", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var obj2Return = dynMethod.Invoke(obj2, null);
}
```

Comment: Yes, i wanna do that.
I'm search in google and stack but i can't find how to fix this because when i'm get property. It's just return null.
Thank you for your link.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys!

I'm done :)

I just Create Property `get{}` `set{}` and use this code :D

> PropertyInfo p = this.GetType().GetProperty("LoaiSP_BUS", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

Thanks all!