# How to get local Object Variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Currently i develop something in Unity using C#.

Let's say i have define below variable, these script is in same file and Orange is **Prefab** :

```
private GameObject orange;
private GameObject avocado;
```

then, i want to **access/get it's Object** by **Name/String** (Because future development will using many **Dynamic Variable**) , i have tried it using `GetType()` but no luck, for example :

```
void Awake() {

orange = (GameObject)Resources.Load ("fruits/Orange", typeof(GameObject)); //getting Orange Prefab
avocado = (GameObject)Resources.Load ("fruits/Avocado", typeof(GameObject)); //getting Avocado Prefab

}  

void Start() {

//Here, i try to get orange/avocado/other fruitname by string
GameObject orangeObj = (GameObject) this.GetType().GetField("orange").GetValue(this); 

GameObject _orange = Instantiate ( orangeObj, new Vector3 (elem_1_pos_x, elem_1_pos_y, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

}
```

Above code will give me error : "**Object Reference not set to an instance of an object**" which means it still not getting the orange object.

Any Idea or Suggestion ?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé i try to Read/Access `Orange Prefab` by string, but if you have better method please let me know...

Comment: @RomanoZumbé can't be like that. in `Start()` method, i want to get Orange `GameObject` by string. In Future, it will be dynamic. i.e "grape", "avocado", etc...

Comment: `GetField` only gets public static and instance fields by default. You need to specifically tell it to look for private fields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95910/find-a-private-field-with-reflection/95973#95973

Comment: Hi @31eee384 i got it, but how to convert `FieldInfo` to `GameObject` ?

Comment: You already have the code for that in your question.

Comment: Hi @31eee384 amazing, it solved :) This save me hours... you can write your answer, so i can say thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Suggestion in Questions's comment. I found an answer, Change :

```
GameObject orangeObj = (GameObject) this.GetType().GetField("orange").GetValue(this);
```

to

```
GameObject orangeObj = (GameObject) this.GetType().GetField("orange", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(this);
```