# Reflection, get explicit interface property 'backing field' name

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a way to get the name of an explicit interface property backing field?

For example, for:

```
public interface I
{
    string PPPP { get; }
}

public class C: I
{
    private string _other_field = default!; // random private field, just to fill.
    public string S => _s_backing; // random property, just to fill.

    private string _s_backing = default!;
    string I.PPPP => _s_backing; // <--- looking for this one!
}
```

For property `PPPP` I'm looking to figure up the string `"_s_backing"`.

I mean. Is there a way to create this helper:

```cs
Helpers.DoSomeReflectionMagic( typeof(C), "PPPP" ) 
// I expect, it returns: `_s_backing`.
```

What I tried: I was digging into `typeof(C)` properties, but I didn't find the backing field anywhere. Maybe there is no way to get it.

---

The underlying XY problem:

```cs
public interface ITree<T>
{
    T? Parent { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> Children { get; }
}

public class Category: ITree<Category>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category? MyParentCategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> MySubCategories { get; set; }

    // Implementing interface
    Category? ITree<Category>.Parent => MyParentCategory;;
    IEnumerable<Category> ITree<Category>.Children => MySubCategories;
}

// dbcontext with fluent api to configure model blah blah

public static class DbContextTreeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetRoots<T>(this MyDbContext ctx)
    {
        var backingfieldname =  // <-- The Y problem
            Helpers
            .DoSomeReflectionMagic(typeof(T), "Parent");

        return
            ctx
            .Set<T>()
            .Where(q => EF.Property<T?>(q, backingfieldname) == null)
            .AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

I would like to do:

```cs
var ctx = MyDbContextFactory.NewContext();
var mainCategories = ctx.GetRoots<Category>();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95910/find-a-private-field-with-reflection

Comment: The property getter can contain any arbitrary code. You cannot just assume that it returns a field. If you know the name `_s_backing`, you can get the `FieldInfo` of that, but that's it.

Comment: @Sweeper, is what I suspected. Can you post your comment as answer?

Comment: I posted it as a comment because I didn't really say anything too useful... Perhaps this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info) and you can explain what you're ultimately trying to do, so I can potentially post a more useful answer?

Comment: @Sweeper, you are clever, bro. I posted the X problem on Q. (just a minimal example)